# Sql query in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I would like to execute such a command:

```
SELECT number.phone_number 
FROM number 
LEFT JOIN ordered_number 
ON ordered_number.number_id=number.id 
WHERE ordered_number.order_id=123
```

with Yii2. I do this:

```
$numery = Number::find()
                    ->select('number.phone_number')
                    ->leftJoin('ordered_number', ['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.id'])
                    ->where(['ordered_number.order_id' => 123])
                    ->createCommand()
                    ->rawSql;
```

But I get then this:

```
'SELECT `number`.`phone_number` FROM `number` LEFT JOIN `ordered_number` ON `ordered_number`.`number_id`='number.id' WHERE `ordered_number`.`order_id`=123'
```

Which doesn't work. When I put the first thing right into my base, I get 4 results, which is correct. But when I do (I think exactly the same) with Yii, I have troubles, because it is null. The only differences between what I have written and what appears after rawSql, are ` and '.

Comment: Is it still `null` if you remove `->select('number.phone_number')` so all fields are returned (and of course with `all()` at the end instead of `->createCommand()->rawSql`)

Comment: Yes, I still get empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I've just read docs for this method - it should be:

```
->leftJoin('ordered_number', 'ordered_number.number_id = number.id')
```

because using the `where()` kind of conditions with array leads to comparing field to string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/13b10bdb9a30cd6d4cc61a76f70c26085e94a90b) could help you a lot , the comments of ActiveRecord.